# A function, to apply a function to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function, that applies a function to a list. I am trying to capitalise all the words in a list but can't get it to work. Here is what I've done so far:

```
list = ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test")

def firstFunction(x):
    return list.upper()

print firstFunction
```

The error I get is:

```
<function firstFunction at 0x0000000002352A58>
```

I'm really stuck on what to do next, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I've just changed it but it's still not working:

```
mylist = ("hello", "this", "is", "james")

def firstFunction(x):
    return may(lambda: x.upper(), mylist)

print firstFunction()
```

Comment: Try a list comprehension: [x.upper() for x in list]

Comment: `list = ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test")` is a tuple, an `immutable`, you cannot alter it !!!

Comment: The question set states that I have to write a function and a list and apply the function to all elements of the list. What would be a better thing to do than capitalise it then?

Comment: It's advisable not to name variables that are already reserved as python keywords such as `list,str,int,pass`,etc...

Comment: `<function firstFunction at 0x0000000002352A58>` is not an error.  It is the string representation of the function object `firstFunction`.  You are printing the function *object* with `print firstFunction`. You need to add parentheses to *call* the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't an error.  It is the function's address in memory.  You are seeing it because you didn't invoke the function.

Overall, there are three problems with your code:

1. You are not invoking the function.  Adding `(...)` after it will do this.
2. You are not passing in an argument to the function, which it requires.
3. There is no `upper` method on a tuple (`list` in this case is a tuple).

Below is a fixed version of the code that does what I think you want:

```
# Don't name a variable 'list' -- it overshadows the built-in.
lst = ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test")

def firstFunction(x):
    return tuple(y.upper() for y in x)

print firstFunction(lst)
```

Output:

```
('HELLO', 'THIS', 'IS', 'A', 'TEST')
```

Here are some references on everything done here:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper

Comment: This won’t work either as `firstFunction` takes one argument.  The TO should a) remove the argument in the method definition or b) change `list.upper()` to `x.upper()` and pass `list` as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks it got rid of the error, but now I'm being told that firstFunction() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given). What does this mean?

Comment: @JaAntr - That's because you need to give the function an argument.  You built it to take one.  See my edit.

Comment: add link to list comprehensions documentation?

Comment: @Dave - Well, I don't want to do that because I didn't use one here.  What you see inside `tuple` is a _generator expression_, and I gave a reference to that.

Answer (score 4):

While other answers are great, I want to mention that there's already a function in python,  called [map()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), and it does almost exactly what you need:

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the
>   results..... The iterable
>   arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object; the result is
>   always a list.

So you code becomes

```
print map(str.upper, lst)
```

or, if you need a tuple, then:

```
print tuple(map(str.upper, lst))
```

You don't need anonymous lambda function here, because [str.upper()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) accepts one argument. I think there's a debate about how pythonic this functional programming is, but I personally like it sometimes.

Comment: There is no upper global in Python.

Comment: Yea, you want `str.upper`.  Also, the reason most people didn't use `map` is that a generator expression is often preferred.  That is really just a style issue though.  However, `map` _does_ return a list, so you need to put it in `tuple`.

Comment: @iCodez yeah, was on mobile, let me extend answer a bit

Answer (score 3):

Actually nor the list, nor the tuple has no a method `.upper()`.
So to achieve this you could just execute this statement:

`print tuple(x.upper() for x in ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test"))`

http://codepad.org/MZ14yXeV

or this one:

`print map(lambda x: x.upper(), ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test"))`

http://codepad.org/kc1LaNCY

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test")
```

is a tuple, an immutable, you cannot alter it, use,

```
print tuple((ele.upper() for ele in list))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most pythonic one:

```
def cap(tup):
    return map(str.upper, tup)

>>> tup = ("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test")
>>> cap(tup)
['HELLO', 'THIS', 'IS', 'A', 'TEST']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do involves [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print [firstFunction(x) for x in list]
```

what this does is: construct the list whose elements are the result of applying the function
to each of the items in you input list and then printing it.

Some (hopefully helpful) comments

- It is bad practice to name a variable `list`; even though it is not a keyword,
  it is the name of a fundamental python type, so re-binding it could cause confusion
  elsewhere.
- In your definition `def firstFunction(list)` -- the name `list` that appears in the
  argument list does not have any relationship to the `list` variable that was defined earlier in your example.  You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules/292498#292498) or the python documentation to understand how the scoping rules work in python.